# How to group by a price confined to a dynamically generated ceiling?

Tags: c#, linq, ceil, linq-group

I have a table of `items` with several properties but to keep it short, it has property `price`.

I want to group a `List<Item>` into groups of price ranges.
The catch is that the price ranges (ceilings ...) have to be dynamically generated.

When the ceilings are static, things work fine (Using LINQ)

```
decimal[] ceilings = new decimal[] { 0, 10M, 100M, 500M, 5000M, 50000M };
var grouped = items.GroupBy( x => ceilings.First( y => y >= x.Price );
```

I'm in search of a good algorithm to generate the ceilings group on the fly based on the price of the `items` list.

I'm struggling with figuring out the `step size` though.
I have a couple of ideas in my head such as finding the difference between the `Max()` and `Min()` of that list and using that to generate a list of ceilings.

Any ideas?

Comment: From your question, it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want a certain number of groups containing a roughly equal number of items? Or do you want some other distribution of items in the groups (price tiers, or top 10, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

A [bucket sort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) might do the trick.

Follow the literature.  If my memory serves correctly there are algorithms for creating buckets that have the same number of entries.  And of course, you can always just sort into (Max - Min)/N for N uniform sized buckets.